# Is 'Good Luck & Bad Luck' same as 'Lucky and Unlucky'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is 'Good Luck & Bad Luck' same as 'Lucky and Unlucky' example:

I have a very bad luck as i always fall down & i am unlucky as i always fall down?

Comment: No, *good luck* or *bad luck* alone is not *lucky* or *unlucky*. Compare your own sentences. When you **have** *bad luck* you are *unlucky*. So, ***lucky*** means ***having good luck*** and ***unlucky*** means ***having bad luck***.

Comment: Luck is a *noun*, lucky is an *adjective*.

Comment: 'Lucky' is the state of receiving good luck. 'Unlucky' is the state of receiving bad luck.

Comment: 'Unlucky' is the state of receiving bad luck. 'Lucky' is the state of receiving good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Your example sentence is correct and makes correct use of both *bad luck* and *unlucky***

---

[Luck](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luck) is:

> (noun)
>   the events or circumstances that operate for or against an individual

[Lucky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lucky) is:

> (adjective)
>   having good luck

*(Unlucky being the opposite of lucky)*

---

Importantly, luck itself is a noun and can be either good or bad. That is, you can either **have** good luck (and therefore **be** lucky) or have bad luck (and be unlucky).

Note that, in general - if somebody is considered to have "a lot of luck", the implication is that they had a lot of *good* luck.

Comment: I personally also associate a recurrence of luck with somebody *who is* lucky. I could say *that* ***was lucky*** to talk about a past event. But, for me, if somebody *is lucky*, I take it to mean that they have more of a pattern of luck than others (it at least seems that lucky things are more likely to happen to them). This is similar to the "lucky rabbit's foot" which is imagined to contain and impart luck.